# Countdown Timer that doesn't reset when you refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I Need to have a code for the timer that doesn't reset the countdown timer even you refresh the page.

I saw sample code at **keith wood plug in**, but don't know how to implement this in my **html file.**
here's the link :

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

I hope somebody could help me! thanks! :)

I just need **Hour, Minutes and Seconds** to show. And after the Time given, there is a prompt box that will show *"Time is up! "* . This one is for the online exam we are developing. Thank you so Much! :)

Comment: There are implementation instructions at that link. Have you followed them? What errors have you encountered?

Comment: What you are looking for is in the `relative` ab on that link and looks like `$('#until300s').countdown({until: +300});`

Comment: Yes. I did what is instructed to that link. I included the links inside my head tag but I'm having trouble on setp 3 which is :

"Connect the countdown functionality to your divs"

please help on how to implement the keith wood plugin inside my html file. thanks! Abhilash :)

Comment: I downloaded the CSS and javascript files already. So far, my hhtml file contains:

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">@import "jquery.countdown.css";</style> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" >
$('#significantShort2').countdown({until: '+1h +1m +15s', format: 'YOWDHMS', significant: 2}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>

Comment: *can you show the step by step implementation of the plugin? the html, js, and css files.Please. thanks a lot!

Comment: Try this link http://jsbin.com/isuqeb/1/edit

Comment: You may need to use cookies to store the end date of the question (the first time you visited the page + a certain amount of time). Keep in mind that javascript is not secure at all and anyone could "cheat" at your exam. You can for exemple add an extra verification in php in order to prevent that.

Comment: Thanks Bali, kinda newbi in web development. Don't know how to use cookies. do you know a good website that can help me to learn cookie on its simplest way? thank ou so much for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

If you know that the user will have local cache enabled and able to store data, you could save 2 values to `localStorage`, 1 for the `currentTime` and 1 for the `targetTime`. Then you compare the 2 in an interval and if `currentTime > targetTime`, display your message.

Also bind to the `onbeforeunload` event and save the new currentTime back into `localStorage`. This will give you the persisted countdown you are seeking.

Here is an example of how you can do this:

```
var interval;
let minutes = 1;
let currentTime = localStorage.getItem('currentTime');
let targetTime = localStorage.getItem('targetTime');
if (targetTime == null && currentTime == null) {
  currentTime = new Date();
  targetTime = new Date(currentTime.getTime() + (minutes * 60000));
  localStorage.setItem('currentTime', currentTime);
  localStorage.setItem('targetTime', targetTime);
}
else{
  currentTime = new Date(currentTime);
  targetTime = new Date(targetTime);
}

if(!checkComplete()){
  interval = setInterval(checkComplete, 1000);
}

function checkComplete() {
  if (currentTime > targetTime) {
    clearInterval(interval);
    alert("Time is up");
  } else {
    currentTime = new Date();
    document.write(
     "\n <font color=\"white\"> Seconds Remaining:" + ((targetTime - currentTime) / 1000) + "</font>");
  }
}

document.onbeforeunload = function(){
  localStorage.setItem('currentTime', currentTime);
}
```

Note that I would've made a snippet however stackoverflow and other online IDE's are complaining about security breaches. Note that this is perfectly valid and does not breach any security. Save it as a `.js` and run.

To start the "countdown" again, invoke `localStorage.clear()`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include the jQuery library in the head section of your page.
2. Download and include the jQuery Countdown CSS and JavaScript in the head section of your page.
   Alternately, you can use the minimised version jquery.countdown.min.js (13.5K vs 31.4K, 4.4K when zipped).
3. Connect the countdown functionality to your divs.

So, your final code will be:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>jQuery Countdown</title>
    <style type="text/css">@import "jquery.countdown.css";</style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.countdown.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
        var year = new Date();
        year = new Date(year.getFullYear(), 11 - 1, 20);
        $('#dvCountDown').countdown({until: year, format: 'HMS'});
            $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>jQuery Countdown Basics</h1>
<p>Counting down to 20 November <span id="year">2012</span>.</p>
<div id="dvCountDown"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use that script then you'll have to count by date and not a custom countdown value in order for it not to get reset on page refresh: http://jsfiddle.net/qWERa/1/

```
//Custom countdown value starting on page load
$('#CountdownbyValue').countdown({until: '+0h +0m +8s', format: 'HMS',onExpiry: liftOff,});

//Countdown by Date
$('#CountdownbyDate').countdown({until: new Date(2012, 11-1, 17, 10, 10, 10), format: 'HMS',onExpiry: liftOff,});

//Time is up dialog!
function liftOff() {
    alert('Time is up!');
}
```

Full Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js'></script> 
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js'></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://keith-wood.name/css/jquery.countdown.css">
<script type='text/javascript'> 
$(window).load(function(){
//Starts from time of page load
$('#CountdownbyValue').countdown({until: '+0h +0m +8s', format: 'HMS',onExpiry: liftOff,});

//Counts by Date
$('#CountdownbyDate').countdown({until: new Date(2012, 11-1, 17, 10, 10, 10), format: 'HMS',onExpiry: liftOff,});

//Time is up!
function liftOff() { 
    alert('Time is up!'); 
} 
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="CountdownbyValue"></div>
<div id="CountdownbyDate"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Your can also try:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure you want to quit this exam?";
}
```

I suggest you take a look at this [Countdown timer with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3121929)

Comment: the one is resetting also when you refresh the page . I'm looking on how to retain the time in your timer. I have exam and there is a next button, when the user click the next, it will direct the user to next page but the time should be the continuation of the previous page. I hope you can help me on this one. Thanks! :)

Comment: Why don't you put the timer in the page main body with the `window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Are you sure you want to quit this exam?";
}` script and use `iframes tag` for each of those exam pages that way the main page won't reload.

Comment: This is an Example: http://fiddle.jshell.net/vGKJN/1/show/ try closing the page and try clicking the iframe links in the page and watch the timer.