# Save date from countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

happy holidays !

Need help .I'm doing an exam online platform and have a countdown that shows the timer . What  I want is, if the user refresh the page, the timer doesn't reset.

Here's my script:

```
 $(function(){
        var finalDate = new Date();
        if (!$.cookie('deadline')){
            var date = $.cookie('deadline');
            date = Date.now();
            finalDate.setTime(date+@Model.CorrectTime);
            cookie = $.cookie('deadline', timerValue, { expires: 7, path: ':' });
        }else {
            cookie = $.cookie('deadline');
        }

        var date = $.cookie('deadline');
        var finalDate = new Date();
        date = Date.now();
        finalDate.setTime(date+@Model.CorrectTime);
        $.cookie('deadline', date);

        console.log('cookie is ' + cookie);
        $('#clock').countdown({until: cookie})
         .on('update.countdown', function(event) {
             var format = '%H:%M:%S';

             $(this).html(event.strftime(format));
         })
         .on('finish.countdown', function(event) {
             var radios = document.getElementsByName('form');
             for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
                 radios[i].disabled = true;
             }
             $(this).html('Sorry ! Out of time !')
               .parent().addClass('disabled');

         });


    });
```

But it shows that the object cookie can't be converted to date format.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convert the date to a string before adding it to the cookie. While retrieving create a new date object from the saved date.

Answer (score 0):

not related to your code but i think you i"ll find this post helpful. it worked for me [Countdown Timer that doesn't reset when you refresh the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412153/countdown-timer-that-doesnt-reset-when-you-refresh-the-page)